# Using continuous output from another process

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write code that is able to use the output from another process that runs continuously. I have tried to use popen() from http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~liberti/public/computing/prog/c/C/FUNCTIONS/popen.html but it only works with processes that finish.

The process monitors something in my house and sends output to the terminal when something happens. Every time output is sent I want to filter it and make something else happen in C++. Is there a way to get that output from a process that keeps running?

EDIT:

I works with popen() but I have encountered a new problem. When I run the process in the code normally it works, but it has to run with sudo. When it runs with sudo it doesn't enter the while loop and gets stuck on the fgets function. I use to following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

  FILE* fp;
  char line[255];
  fp = popen("sudo eibd --trace=5 --listen-local ip:", "r");

  while(fgets( line, sizeof line, fp) != NULL) {
    printf("aa");
    fflush(fp);
    printf("%s", line);
    }
}
```

Comment: If it's outputting to stdout, then can't you just pipe it?  `thingThatIWantToMonitor | myProgram`.

Comment: TCP/IP, Shared memory, message queues, UDP, ... But popen should work with the right flushing

Comment: It would help if you add your code. popen() works fine even for processes that continue to run. What do you mean by "terminal"? Does the process write to stdout, which makes it easy to filter, or really to at terminal? In the 2nd case, you might have to use pseudo-terminals, which makes things a bit more complicated. That's the way ssh or rlogin or xterm work - they start shells that use a pseudo-terminal as their terminal. Each pseudo-terminal has a corresponding master device from which you can grab what goes into the pseudo-terminal.

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be that it buffers the output.

You need to tell it somehow to not buffer it. i.e with python program, you run it with `-u` flag

```
python -u theprocess.py
```

alternatively you can use `stdbuf`:

```
// 0 buffer
stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 command
// line buffer
stdbuf -oL -eL command
```